# In Firefox/Chrome devtools Is there a way to send/edit websocket messages after connection

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, google-chrome-devtools, mozilla, devtools

I have a Safari/Firefox/Chrome browser. My browser has devtools.
Is there a way to happy send/edit websocket messages for existing connection?
Or by plugin?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can grab instance of `websocket` connection and can use it further to send further messages on it.

#### Grab socket connection instance

You must be aware of websocket connection establishment as below:

```
websocket = new WebSocket('your-ws-url-goes-here');
```

Now you can use instance of `websocket` and can use `.send()` and `.close()`.

Your question states that you want to use existing connected web socket, you can look for socket connection instance in source code and can use it for sending further messages.

#### Example to play with

You can play with websocket and its instance here at http://websocket.org/echo.html

**Notice here**

```
var wsUri = "wss://echo.websocket.org/";
```

and function having

```
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

You so you know websocket is connected and having instance in `websocket`

You can open `devtool` and type `websocket` to see all of the option. So in your case you need to find instance of connection so you can play with it.

#### About editing existing message

I couldn't find if there is any way to edit sent messages, and i think it should not be there. You can send new message since earlier message must have been responded already.

Comment: This method only allows to create another WebSocket connection to the server, it doesn't allow to reuse existing connection. OP asked for sending messages within existing connection.

Comment: @adamczi no, you can get a reference to the websocket instance the page is already using and use that.

Comment: @adamczi Getting websocket instance: `devtools -> memory -> heap dump, search "websocket" and expand, right click some of them -> store as a global variable`. There might be several so you need the correct one, check `temp1.url` to see.

Answer (score 13):

1. You can list all WebSocket connections on page in Chrome by opening a console and writing `queryObjects(WebSocket)`. It should list all instances after a while.
2. Then choose the one you want to use and right-click on it and choose "Store object as global variable".
3. This will create a new variable like temp1 so you can send messages with `temp1.send(JSON.stringify({websocket: 'message'}))`.

[image: Chrome console with found WebSockets]

Comment: It's `temp1.send('{your: "message"}')`

Comment: It must be accepted answer! Thank you so much
- Also, i suggest to use JSON.stringify
- `temp1.send(JSON.stringify({ message: "hey" }))`