# Chrome Devtools how to send/edit websocket messages in binary?

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

From the previous question [In Firefox/Chrome devtools Is there a way to send/edit websocket messages after connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59242245/in-firefox-chrome-devtools-is-there-a-way-to-send-edit-websocket-messages-after), I've learned how to load the current WebSocket and send messages using the method shared by Mišo. But now I want to send a message in binary type, since I observe that DevTools -> Network -> WS Message block appears as follows: [Binary Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV70d.png). What can I do to send the same type of data using temp1.send()?

I've tried `temp1.send(0x0065)` but what it appears in the WS Message block was: [101](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P25pH.png).

Comment: Try `new Uint8Array([0x65])`